# Establishing current date in HTML form

Tags: php, html, date, smarty

how can I show current date as default? my page is showing "january 2006" because I use another code that lists date for last 10 years.

Comment: @unex
    $fromDate = date ('Y-m');
     $toDate = date ('Y-m');

Comment: you should put that in the post ;).
You should try `$fromDate = new DateTime(); $toDate = new DateTime();`.

Comment: @unex, thank you a lot :)

Comment: put is as an answer so you can validate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `$fromDate = new DateTime(); $toDate = new DateTime()`;

Comment: and if I will try to do that with if-else?
like if ($i = 1;) {
    condition 
} else {$i = 0;}

Comment: I mean, if current month is .04 then how can I construct it by if-else?